# How to store Base64 string in mySQL as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, blob

I'm trying to insert a base64 string into blob by using the code below, I'm getting a blob added to the database but it's a damaged file with no extension.

Background:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *encodedString = [binaryData base64Encoding];
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image=%@", encodedString];
```

PHP:

```
$json_obj = $_POST['image'];
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$json_obj);
$encodedData= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($encodedData)));
$blob = $encodedData;
$dbHandle = mysql_connect("--------","-------","------");
$dbFound = mysql_select_db("----------");

if($dbFound){


    $check = "INSERT INTO `Images`(`imageId`, `image`, `userId`, `dateCreated`) ".
           "VALUES ".
           "('','$blob','0',null)";

    $retval = mysql_query( $check, $dbHandle );

    if(!$retval)
    {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $blob . '" />';
}
else{
      print "No Connection";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
$encodedData= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($json_obj)));
```

Then change `echo "BLOB: " . "---" .  $blob;` to:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $blob. '" />';
```

Otherwise you are just dumping the `string` value that's why you get this result.

Comment: I'm not tryna output it or anything, I'm just getting a damaged file with no extension in the database

Comment: It still displays the image file perfectly but having a damaged file with no extension in mysql

Comment: Changed my question with the code provided so you can see it more clearly

Comment: @Dave Try `$_FILES["image"]` instead of `$_POST["image"]`. And remove `$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$json_obj);`.

Comment: That gives me <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,DQo=" />. With a damaged file much smaller in size in the database, I'll add a bit of the background going to php to my question

Comment: Figured it out, just decoded it from objective c before sending it. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [mysql base64](http://base64encode.net/mysql-to-base64) function: `TO_BASE64('string');` ?